# onpaste input event in blazor and typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, blazor

The `@onpaste` is a blazor DOM event executed when content is pasted in an input.
now, I want to get this text content from typescript (blazor doesn't support it).

razor:

```
@inject IJSRuntime _Js

<input class="otp-input"
           @ref="myInputRef"
           @onpaste="HandleOnPaste" />
@code {

    private ElementReference myInputRef { get; set; }

    private async Task HandleOnPaste()
    {
        var pastedData = await _js.InvokeAsync<string?>("OtpInput.getPastedData")
        
        // DO Something
    }
    
}
```

ts:

```
class OtpInput {
    static getPastedData(e: ClipboardEvent) {

        let pastedData = e.clipboardData!.getData('text');

        return pastedData;
    }
}
```

this does not work and return error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clipboardData')`

Comment: What is supposed to be `inputRef`? Did you mix it with  `myInputRef`? However, I doubt you could get what you want from the element reference. Maybe there is an argument that you could add in `HandleOnPaste`. Otherwise, you may use [this solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-clipboard-paste-event-example)

Comment: firstly, thanks for your comment. the question code was wrong and now I fixed it. 
and about your answer, technically I can use custom events but I don't want to use this solution. because my project dependencies don't allow me.

Comment: Well, now you're not passing any argument to `getPastedData` while it is supposed to get one. Therefore, `e` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

Blazor now supports registering [custom event arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-event-arguments). The documentation has an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-clipboard-paste-event-example) of using custom event arguments to create a custom clipboard paste event that includes the time of the paste and the user's pasted text.

**Original answer**:

You can use a different approach. Add event listener to the input element using javascript then call dotnet method and pass the event data. I use javascript but you can modify accordingly for typescript.

**pasteInteropHelper.js:**

```
export function addOnPasteEventListener(elem, componentInstance) {

    elem.onpaste = (e) => {
        var text = e.clipboardData.getData('text');

        componentInstance.invokeMethod('HandlePaste', text);
    }
}
```

**razor component:**

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<input @ref="_inputRef" />

@code {
    private ElementReference _inputRef;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./pasteInteropHelper.js");

            var selfReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("addOnPasteEventListener", _inputRef, selfReference);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void HandlePaste(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```