# How to get pasted text in blazor?

Tags: event-handling, blazor, paste

I have `input`, which on I want to paste text. I use `inPaste` event and how I can pasted text?

```html
<Blazorise.Addon AddonType="Blazorise.AddonType.Start" Class="m-2 w-25">
  <Blazorise.AddonLabel>Package ID</Blazorise.AddonLabel>
  <Blazorise.TextEdit @bind-Text="packageID" @onpaste="OnScan" @onchange="OnPackageIDIputChange" />
</Blazorise.Addon>
```

I try to use EventArgs like param, but it not work.

```cs
void OnScan(EventArgs pasteString)
{
    foreach (string pattern in codePattern)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(pasteString, pattern))
        {
            this.productCode = this.packageID;
            this.packageID = "";
        }
    }
    if (IsGuid(this.productCode))
    {
        this.packageID = this.productCode;
        this.productCode = "";
    }
}
```

[image]

Also I see resolve of this problem on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73608171/onpaste-input-event-in-blazor-and-typescript), but I don't want create new js function for every situation.

Comment: Did you try using `ClipboardEventArgs`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom event arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-event-arguments). The documentation has [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-clipboard-paste-event-example) for exactly what you need.

> Declare a custom name (`oncustompaste`) for the event and a .NET class
> (`CustomPasteEventArgs`) to hold the event arguments for this event:
>
> `CustomEvents.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorSample.CustomEvents;

[EventHandler("oncustompaste", typeof(CustomPasteEventArgs), 
    enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: true)]
public static class EventHandlers
{
}

public class CustomPasteEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DateTime EventTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string? PastedData { get; set; }
}
```

> Add JavaScript code to supply data for the EventArgs subclass with the
> preceding handler in a JavaScript initializer. The following example
> only handles pasting text, but you could use arbitrary JavaScript APIs
> to deal with users pasting other types of data, such as images.
>
> `wwwroot/{PACKAGE ID/ASSEMBLY NAME}.lib.module.js`:

```js
export function afterStarted(blazor) {
  blazor.registerCustomEventType('custompaste', {
    browserEventName: 'paste',
    createEventArgs: event => {
      return {
        eventTimestamp: new Date(),
        pastedData: event.clipboardData.getData('text')
      };
    }
  });
}
```

> In the preceding example, the `{PACKAGE ID/ASSEMBLY NAME}` placeholder
> of the file name represents the package ID or assembly name of the
> app.

Usage:

```
<Blazorise.TextEdit @bind-Text="packageID" @oncustompaste="OnScan" @onchange="OnPackageIDIputChange" />

@code{
    void OnScan(CustomPasteEventArgs args)
    {
        var pastedData = args.PastedData;
        // ...
    }
}
```